# Check results of spread operator with startsWith or like

Tags: groovy, spock

Let's say I have:

```
class Conflict extends RuntimeException {
    Conflict(String message) {
        super(message)
    }
}
```

and

```
class Conflicts extends RuntimeException {

    List<Conflict> conflicts = new ArrayList<>()

    Conflicts(List<Conflict> conflicts) {
        this.conflicts = conflicts
    }
}
```

In [Spock](http://spockframework.org/), I typically check exception messages with [spread operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator):

```
def e = thrown(Conflicts)
e.conflicts*.message == ["my expected message 1", "my expected message 2"]
```

Is there any way how to check `startsWith`, `like` and other operations in similar succinct way in Groovy?

Comment: Maybe: `["my expected message 1", "my expected message 2"].every { it.contains('expected') }`?

Comment: `e.conflicts*.message.findAll{it=~"my expected message 1|my expected message 2"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`every`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#every(groovy.lang.Closure)) for that:

```
def e = thrown(Conflicts)
e.conflicts*.message.every { it.startsWith("my expected message" }
```